# Como fazer um setTimout mas só quando não tem ação na tela?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

Estou querendo uma ideia, como faço um SetTimout só quando usuário deixar de mexer na pagina. Exemplo, estou com 2 telas. Uma é a tela de reposo e outra é a home. quando usuário entrar no sistema ele vai pra home, enquanto ele estiver mexendo nada acontece, se ele parar de mexer por uns x segundos dispara um setTimout e sai da tela da home para a de reposo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link que ele explica o que você precisa: [Detect Idle](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/detecting_if_the_user_is_idle_or_inactive.htm) - Basicamente é adicionar eventos para todas as ações de mouse e teclado, e quando parar de checar, começar um `setTimeOut`... agora a lógica para isso deve ser bem trabalhada.

Comment: Valeu amigo vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado